# Creating a Role with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to use the discord API to make a bot that its going to create a role and add a person to it. I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

```js
async function role(message){
    try {
        let guild = client.guild.get(236824834066219009);
        guild.roles.create({
            data:{
            name:"asd",
            color:"grey",
        },
        reason:"asd",
    })
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "asd");
        let user = 236824834066219009;
        await user.addrole(role).catch(console.error);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is because since `discord.js` v12 there have been a lot of changes.

You can't use `.find()` on `roles` anymore you have to access their `cache` first so you need to replace `let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "asd");` with `let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "asd");`

You also can't add roles using `addrole()`, you need to use `roles.add()` so you need to replace `user.addrole(role)` with `user.roles.add(role)`

You can also make your code more efficient by not having to find the `role`, you can just use `.then()` to add the role to the `user`, which you can also pass through as a parameter in your function along with the `guild`, like so:

```js
async function role(message, user, guild){
    try {
        guild.roles.create({
            data:{
            name:"asd",
            color:"grey",
        },
        reason:"asd",
    }).then((role) => user.roles.add(role)).catch(console.error);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```